# Google Places API for android - getting 0 photos for cities

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using Google places API for android to let the user select cities in the world. Then I use the placeId to get an image to something similar to google maps.

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK1Iy.jpg)

Every single time I'm getting the photos bundle successfully but it contains no images. It works just fine if I use the placeId of any restaurant or cafe or any other single spot but not for a whole city.

Here's the method I'm using to get the images.

```
public void loadPlaceImage(final ImageView imageView, String placeId) {

    /**
     * Load a bitmap from the photos API asynchronously
     * by using buffers and result callbacks.
     */

    Places.GeoDataApi.getPlacePhotos(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlacePhotoMetadataResult>() {


                @Override
                public void onResult(PlacePhotoMetadataResult photos) {
                    if (!photos.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn\'t receive photos bundle successfully.");
                        return;
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "Photo bundle received successfully");

                    PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.getPhotoMetadata();
                    if (photoMetadataBuffer.getCount() > 0) {
                        // Display the first bitmap in an ImageView in the size of the view
                        photoMetadataBuffer.get(0)
                                .getScaledPhoto(mGoogleApiClient, imageView.getWidth(),
                                        imageView.getHeight())
                                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlacePhotoResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResult(PlacePhotoResult placePhotoResult) {
                                        if (!placePhotoResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Couldn\'t retrieve the photo successfully.");
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully retrieved photo from photo bundle.");

                                        imageView.setImageBitmap(placePhotoResult.getBitmap());
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "0 images in the buffer.");
                    }
                    photoMetadataBuffer.release();
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code in my android studio, it hadn't problem in your code.

I guess you forgot to add meta-data in Manifest.

```
  <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOURKEY"/>
</application>
```

it is for reference to set up your "Android KEY"
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup

https://console.developers.google.com/apis   (this Link can set your key)

By the way, you can use:

Log.d(TAG,"result getStatus   "+result.getStatus().getStatus());

to check your error message, hope it will help you